# What happens if we use both strong and retain for the same IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Can we use Strong and Retain for the same IBOutlet?
What happens if we do so?

Something like this
@property (retain, strong) NSNumber *property;

Comment: Show an example of what you mean. How are you giving two different properties to the same outlet?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I cannot say the correct answer because I didn't know it. I got knowledge from the replies. If someone marked the answer, it would be helpful to the others who are looking for this questions

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ARC, you will get the same effect. No matter if you're using `strong` or `retain` attribute.

[From Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Instead of you having to remember when to use retain, release, and autorelease, ARC evaluates the lifetime requirements of your objects and automatically inserts appropriate memory management calls for you at compile time. The compiler also generates appropriate dealloc methods for you. **In general, if you’re only using ARC the traditional Cocoa naming conventions are important only if you need to interoperate with code that uses manual reference counting**.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use Strong **and** Retain for the same IBOutlet? What happens if we do so?

*[Emphasis added]*

Assuming ARC, but it probably makes no difference:

Yes, and the compiler just behaves as if you only typed one of them (which are synonyms).

Indeed the compiler doesn't seem to mind how often you type an attribute as long as you write an incompatible combination, e.g.:

```
@property (copy, copy, copy, copy) NSNumber *copiedProperty;
@property (retain, strong, retain, strong) NSNumber *strongProperty;
```

are accepted (and produce identical code to the equivalent declarations containing just one `copy` or `retain`/`strong`)! But:

```
@property (weak, copy) NSNumber *willProduceAnErr;
```

is not because it's meaningless.